# : Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: json, ios, swift

Я посмотрел видео по работе с JSON, где он применялся для получения информации о погоде из сайта darksky.net. Почему-то при создании URLRequest система выдает nil. Видео для работы со Swift 3. Работаю на Swift 5

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
        override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
            
    Weather.forecast(withLocation: "37.8267, -122.4233"){  (results: [Weather]) in

    for result in results{

    print("\(result)")
                
                }
            }
    }

}


    import Foundation

    struct Weather {

    let summary: String

    let icon: String

    let temperature: Double
        
        

    enum SerializationError:Error{

    case missing(String)

    case invalid(String, Any)
        
        }
        
        

     init(json: [String:Any]) throws {

     guard let summary = json["summary"] as? String else{throw SerializationError.missing("summary is missing")}

    guard let icon = json["icon"] as? String else {throw SerializationError.missing("icon is missing")}

    guard let temperature = json["temperatureMax"] as? Double else {throw SerializationError.missing("temp is missing")}

    self.summary = summary

    self.icon = icon

    self.temperature = temperature

}

    static let basePath = "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/forecast/b8ad8e6f9255acf0628893f8e17d7dd1/"

    static func forecast(withLocation location: String, completion: @escaping ([Weather]) -> ()){

      let url = URL(string: basePath + location)!
          
            //let request =  URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
            

    let session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)
           

    let task = session.dataTask(with: url){(data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

    var forecastArray: [Weather] = []

    if let data = data{

    do{

   if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options:  []) as? [String:Any]{

   if let dailyForecasts = json["daily"] as? [String:Any]{

    if let dailyData = dailyForecasts["data"] as? [[String:Any]]{

   for dataPoint in dailyData{

    if let weatherObject = try? Weather(json: dataPoint){

    forecastArray.append(weatherObject)
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

    catch{
                        
                    }

    completion(forecastArray)
                }
            }
    

    task.resume()
    }
    }
```

Comment: Выложите код в читаемом виде или дайте ссылку на gist.github

Comment: До исправлений вместо session был request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!) , task  = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) с тем же замыканием. Пробовал создать свойство и там преобразовать строку в url, а потом указать это свойство в URLRequest, но это не помогло

Comment: Все, понял. Скорее всего, тут дело не в самом URL, а в тексте запроса

Answer (score 1):

А если попробовать без реквеста? )
заменить ваши строки этими

```
33  let url = URL(string: basePath + location)!
34
35
36
37
38  // let request = ... Это закоментировать
39
40
41  let session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)
42  let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую

Comment: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
2019-04-08 19:09:37.057114+0300 JSON[2679:248922] Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb) po url error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x20).
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.
Сообщения в консоли до и после проверки на наличие url

Comment: А где у вас проверка на наличие url ? Без кода в текстовом виде проблематично помогать :(

Comment: Я в консоли смотрю. Если бы url был, он бы там напечатался. Насколько я знаю, так можно проверить, присвоено ли какому-то свойству нужное значение

Comment: А вот эта ваша связка basePath + location рождает правильный URL?

Comment: Если Вы имеете ввиду соответствие url схеме запроса на сайте, то соответствует

Answer (score -1):

Ошибка была в пробеле между координатами в location, т .е. Unexpectedly found nil может возникать тогда, когда запрос написан неправильно. Например, Вы не ту букву указали в токене, или, как в моем случае, пробел поставили(этого в запросе делать нельзя), или не там / поставили